# Best way of searching for address in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web site that would have to utilize google APIs for addresses,  geolocation and possibly geofencing.

This is what's problematic for me.

-User registers on web site and says that he will work in location A and 5 km around that location.
-Consumer searches the site to see if he can find someone in location B. Now, that location B might fall into 5 km radius around location A, and than again it doesn't have to.

The problem is obvious. How do I know that location B is in 5 km radius of location A?

Now, let's spice it up a bit.

[image]

So now we have multiple users that each have their own unique radius of working. Only users A, B and C can work where we searched. User D can't!

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

This would be the information I would have.
-All the locations of users and their radius of working. 
-Location we are searching.

I am looking for abstract solution here and possibly for links to some kind of tutorials that would be close to what I'm asking here.

If I have misplaced tags for this question please tell me so I can correct them. You have to forgive me but I am new to this kind of problematic.

Comment: Maybe I understand the question wrong, but all you have to do is to calculate the distance between user-location and working-location. When it's less than the radius  the user is willing to work there

Comment: Yes, but that would force me to go through all of my addresses and check for each and every one of them if they can work in user selected address. Is there a way to load all these addresses in google and tell google that that address is providing something in certain radius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to come up with a solution where I do not do the calculation but rather rely on database. Since this is SQL Server(I don't know if this is available on other database providers) I get to use data type called geography.

I can create the table this way

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[Address] Script Date: 19.2.2016. 13:10:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Location] [geography] NOT NULL,
[Radius] [decimal](7, 2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Adresa] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Than I can insert some value in the table like this

```
INSERT INTO Address(Location, Radius)
VALUES(geography::Point(43.0026805, 17.2788935, 4326), 2);
```

After that comes the querying of the table. Now before I make the query I am required to initialize the data type of geography. 
This would be an example of how to query this table

```
GO
DECLARE @p GEOGRAPHY = geography::Point(42.9945355, 17.2634869, 4326)
SELECT *, Location.STBuffer(Radius * 1000).STIntersects(@p) as Valid
FROM Address
```

This is the best soulution I can come up. I believe it is faster than manually doing the mathematical operations although I do not see any way that database would be avoiding those operations. The only difference here is that I can put spatial index on geopgraphy data type which would yield in faster execution.